# Grid - Hiding row and textblock display issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple dialog  - A `Grid` with 4 `TextBlock`'s wherein I bind the visibility of the 2nd and 3rd `TextBlock` to a property but it doesn't work as expected i.e., the conditional message appears truncated when viewing the dialog. The 2 variants of the dialog are as below:

Some Text

*Conditional Message 1*

B C

or

Some Text

*Conditional Message 2*

B C

The XAML of the dialog is as attached below.

```
    <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:cl="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABC.DrillDown"
            xmlns:iwpf="clr-namespace:ABC.Mvvm.Wpf;assembly=ABC.Mvvm.Wpf"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="ABC.DrillDown.Views.MessageView"
            Title="{Binding WindowTitle}"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MaxWidth="525" MinWidth="525" Background="White" MinHeight="275" MaxHeight="275">
    <Window.Resources>
            <iwpf:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="514" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="64"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TransactionsModified, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <RowDefinition.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
<!--Hide Row-1-->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TransactionsModified}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RowDefinition.Style>
                </RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TransactionsDeleted, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <RowDefinition.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
<!--Hide Row-2-->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TransactionsDeleted}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RowDefinition.Style>
                </RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="12"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" xml:space="preserve" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="478">Some Text           </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TransactionsModified}" Visibility="{Binding TransactionsModified, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  xml:space="preserve" Width="0" >
               Conditional Text - 1
            </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TransactionsDeleted}" Visibility="{Binding TransactionsDeleted, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" xml:space="preserve" Width="0">
                Conditional Text - 2
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" xml:space="preserve" Width="425">
                Text 3

                Text 4
            </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            </Window>

C
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of RowDefinition where there is a wrong Height (you should remove this part)

```
   Height="{Binding TransactionsModified, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Of course binding Height directly to a bool makes no sense: you already have the more reasonable triggers in the following part (they look fine at first sight)